# Selecting a 1% sample in Aginity Workbench SQL

Tags: sql, database, random, netezza, aginity

I need to scoop up a random sample of 1% of the records in a table (with the number of rows growing every second).

My idea is to

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   random(),
   name,
   age,
   registrationNumber
FROM everGrowingTable
ORDER BY random desc
LIMIT (
    (select count(*) from everGrowingTable) * 0.01
) -- this is attempting to get 1%
```

The compiler complains about the `*` operator. It is fine when I hard code the table size however.

I've tried [IBM documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_functions_expressions_operators.html), but this talks about calculations using known values, not values that grow (such is that case in my table)

There doesn't seem to be a Aginity SQL function that does this. I've notice the MINUS function in the Aginity Workbench Intellisense, but alas, no multiplication equivalent.

Comment: What if you count a specific field? Name, for example

Comment: no dice fails with "expecting `ALL' or `FCONST' or `ICONST' or `PARAM' or `'-''"

Comment: Ok, try this:
`select DISTINCT
   random()
   ,name
   ,age
   ,registrationNumber
from
   everGrowingTable
order by random desc
limit ((select count(*)*0.01 from everGrowingTable))`

Comment: @ Antonio Veneroso Contreras  WORKS thanks! Simple and effective. Happy Friday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use window functions in a subquery to assign a random number to each record and compute the total record number, and then do the filtering in the outer query :

```
SELECT name, age, registrationNumber
FROM (
    SELECT 
        name, 
        age, 
        registrationNumber,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY random()) rn,
        COUNT(*) OVER() cnt 
    FROM everGrowingTable
) x 
WHERE rn <= cnt / 100
ORDER BY rn
```